# NO error but still messages are moved to DLQ

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, dlq

I am using SQS queue for task execution and DLQ enabled for this queue. In my case successfully processed task messages are also moved to DLQ..

We cross checked in our logs for particular task no nay error log but still could see that task in DLQ. Why successfully processed tasks are moving to DLQ. Also its happening in our PROD env. Its not happening in our local envs.

Using `sqs-consumer`  npm package for consume message. Please share your ideas.

Comment: Are you not deleting the message from the queue after you process it?

Comment: @MarkB yes.....